# Codeigniter update query does not seem work perfectly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table "books".  In my "books" table, I have two foreign keys "product_id" and "cat_id". I want to apply updating the "books" where two foreign keys also changing. Unfortunately, I only success updating the "product_id".

Here is my update query:

```
UPDATE books SET product_id='$product', cat_id='$category'......WHERE books_id='$books_id';
```

And here is my controller:

```
public function updateBook()
{

.....

$id = $this->input->post('books_id');
$product = $this->input->post('product_name');
$category = $this->input->post('category_name');

$this->my_model->updatItem($id, $product, $category, bla..bla..bla);

.....

}
```

Once again, for those two foreign keys, I only success updating the "product" and I wondered what was wrong?

Comment: What code do you have in the `updateItem` method in `my_model`? Is there a reason you're not using CodeIgniter's [Active Record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) for your database updates?

Comment: I have no reason. I just do it as usual I do. I did not familiar with Codeigniter's Active Record

Comment: if you execute the update query like this $this->db->query($update_sql) then there should be no problem

Comment: are you sure data type for product_id, cat_id are same as product_name, category_name respectively

Comment: Hi, I just change my select name from 'category_name' to 'cat_id' and get success

Answer (score 1):

@life4learn - I would recommend you that if you are using codeigniter you must use it active record for queries. There are predefined properties which make your job quicker and easier. And check what you are getting in POST for categories which you are updating.